# Objective-C: How Can Class call global method safely?

Tags: objective-c, button, callback, global

I have tried and got "SIGBRT" exception.
In **Global.m**, I have `methodBGlobal()`.

In ClassA, I included **Global.h** in order to use `methodGlobal()`.
`ClassA.methodA()` has `methodGlobal()` in it.

Then I have button in **Global.m**. Since I do not know how to call `methodGlobal()` properly in **Global.m**. SO I call the `methodGlobal()` through ClassA instance.

```
[mybutton addTarget:ClassA instance action:@selector(methodA:) ...];
```

It does not work. I got "SIGBRT" exception and I do not know that methodGlobal() in ClassA.methodA() was called or not? I want methodGlobal to work.

Comment: How `methodA` is declared? Does it include any parameters?

Comment: @EmptyStack methodA is void function with no parameter. -(void) methodA(){methodGlobal();}

Comment: If so, there should be no `:` in @selector, it should be `[mybutton addTarget:ClassA instance action:@selector(methodA) ...];
`

Comment: @EmptyStack Ah... I will try on tommorow because the project is in company. But I don't think it gonna work. If I corrected, I have tried that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to consider here.

> 1. If the method is a **class method**, then the **target** should be **[ClassA class]**.
> 2. If the method signature doesn't include any arguments , for ex., **-(void) methodA;** then, there should be not colon(":") included in the **@selector**. So, the **selector** should be just **@selector(methodA)**.

Finally the `addTarget:` method should look like,

```
[mybutton addTarget:[ClassA class] action:@selector(methodA) ...];
```

**References:**

1. [**Target-Action**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) from Cocoa Application Competencies for iOS.
2. [**The Target-Action Mechanism**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14)  from Cocoa Fundamentals Guide.

Comment: @EmptyStack you saved my world! Thanx but I still do not understand the logic of the code. If you have good tutorial on internet, please introduce to me. I can only do Objective-C in Company cos I still do not have enough money to buy my own mac. Anyway, really thank you. May I ask you one more question. If it is possible to set global button(not in the class) to activate global method directly?

Comment: @So_CLOSE_BUT_STILL_SO_FAR, Yes. You can set it.

Comment: @EmptyStack, Can you explain to me how to set global button to active global method? I am confusing how to set global button's target since self is not avariable.

Comment: @EmptyStack, I make a new question since it gonna be long. Thanks for all your help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518315/objectivecis-possible-to-set-global-buttonnot-in-the-class-to-activate-global

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[mybutton addTarget:[ClassA class] action:@selector(methodA:) ...];
```

Comment: I know about what you said. But it does not work. I think my question is not clear, sorry for that. I edited my question and hope to get good answer soon

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by making class method like `+ (void) doAction` now you can use this method with the class name like `[ClassName doAction]`