# ObjectiveC:Is possible to set global button(not in the class) to activate global method directly?

Tags: objective-c, button, methods, global, target

Just like the question said.
Is possible to set global button(not in the class) to activate global method directly?
I confused on setting target and action part.

```
import "Global.h"

void methodA() 
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,441,100,30);
    [button addTarget:??? action@selector(methodB????) forControlEvent...];
}

void methodB()
{
}
//end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is set up a nil-targeted action that works with the Responder Chain.

Have a read about it in the [iOS Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) documentation.